# Retornar una imagen en el django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

Mi problema es que nesesito mostrar una imagen predeterminada si no hay una cargada, osea si el condicional es else me muestre una imagen por defecto

Este es mi archivo `models.py`:

```
   class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Nombre')
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Descripcion')
    inserted_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ficha')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Titulo')
    cover_photo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Foto de Portada')
    web_site = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def image_tag(self):
        if self.logo:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50" />' % (self.logo))
        else:
            return mark_safe('no image found')
    image_tag.short_description = 'Imagen del logo'
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'company'
        verbose_name_plural= 'compañia' 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que bastaría con cambiar tu  `'no image found'` por `'<img src="defaultimg.jpg" width="50" height="50" />'`,

```
def image_tag(self):
    if self.logo:
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50" />' % (self.logo))
    else:
        return mark_safe('<img src="defaultimg.jpg" width="50" height="50" />')
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo habia intentado antes pero aun asi sigue sin mostrar la imagen

Comment: Cual es el resultado que obtienes.?

Comment: En terminal me sale esto:                                                                                 
```                                                                                                                "GET /admin/brands/company/img/peiky.jpg/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Jun/2020 23:28:57] "GET /admin/brands/company/img/peiky.jpg/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Jun/2020 23:28:58] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 32460 ```

Comment: En el django admin, donde deberia ir la imágen que resultado tienes? inspecciona elementos y mira que se imprimió

Comment: En el admin me sale esto:  ![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yxnc.png

Comment: Es decir que ese elemento tiene imágen, cuando no tiene que resultado obtienes.?

Comment: El mismo, no cambio; pero si le quito el mark_safe solo me muestra todo el contenido del parentesis en el admin

Comment: La respuesta de @JhoubertRincon es una muy buena opción, el problema es la ruta de la imagen, en el `src` debería ir: `{% static 'defaultimg.jpg' %}` o `{% static 'img/defaultimg.jpg' %}`, dependiendo la estructura de la carpeta `static`.

Comment: Es importante que verifiques el src de tu imagen con el resultado final, utilizando el inspector de elemtnso del navegador. clic derecho y inspeccionar elemento, verás que obtuviste

Comment: Ya lo inspeccione y dice que esta en el directorio correcto pero cuando le doy abrir imagen en otra pagina, dice que el archivo tal vez fue borrado o no existe

Answer (score 0):

```
image=models.FileField(upload_to='pic/%Y/%m/%d',default='defaultimg/defaultimg.png',blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: Por favor, añade una explicación a tu respuesta. De paso te invito a que hagas el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de nuestro sitio.

Comment: Agrega una explicacion y mejora el formato de la respuesta.